# Decomposing any rotation in terms of "elementary rotations".

Tags: geometry, rotations

i was working on something and i'm wondering if the following is true

> Can we decompose any given rotation matrix of angle $\theta$ and along $u$, $A_{u}({\theta})$ in terms of the rotations $M_x(\theta_1),M_y(\theta_2),M_z(\theta_3)$.

This feels like it should be possible to just compose the $3$ elementary rotations with different angles to get any rotation matrix $A_{u}({\theta})$. I know that the rotations are a group for the composition of applications. I feel like i'm lacking knowledge about rotations and that this is obvious. Would those 3 elementary rotation matrix be like a base of a vector space in which any rotation matrix is a "linear combination" of the elementary ones except that it's for the composition and not addition.

Any idea on how to proceed ?

Thank you.

Comment: See Euler angles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but the solution might not be unique. Step 1 is to write out the rotation matrix in terms of the axis and angle, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). Now write the matrix obtained by multiplying the rotations around the three axis. What you get is the rotation matrix  according to [Tait–Bryan XYZ convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix). You can then identify the corresponding coefficients, to get the angles. Let's assume that $c2=\cos\theta_2$ is positive ($0\le\theta_2\le \pi/2$). Then from the table you immediately get $$\theta_1=\mathrm{atan2}(R_{33},-R_{23})
\\\theta_2=\arcsin(R_{13})\\\theta_3=\mathrm{atan2}(R_{11},-R_{12})$$